# How to solve an error - No such module 'Framework' for private framework that is used in main project and internal pod?

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, podspec

We have internal framework (let’s call it Testable) as a target of Application Project. Testable is used in several targets of Application project and we don’t want to extract it to separate repo for a series of reasons. So our setup is following:

```
Workspace(App)
    - Application Project
        - Testable Framework
        - Tests for Testable (uses Testable)
        - Other Internal framework (uses Testable)
        - Tests for Other internal Framework (use Testable)
        - Application 1 (use Testable)
        - Tests for Application 1 (use Testable)
        - Application 2 (use Testable)
        - Tests for Application 2 (use Testable)
        … Other targets
    - Pods Project
        … pods targets
```

Next we introduced new internal framework(let’s call it Science) as a separate project in it’s own repo. Science project is stored close to App and uses Testable by `:path => ‘relative path to project’.`.
Setup is following:

```
Workspace(Science)
    - Science Project
        - Science Framework (uses Testable)
        - Tests for Science Framework
    - Pods Project
        Testable as -> pod 'Testable', :path => ‘../App/Testable'
```

Folders structure:

```
Project Folder
    - App Folder
        - Testable Folder
    - Science Folder
```

Science.podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = ‘Science'
  s.version          = '0.1'
  s.summary          = 'Some Summary’


  s.description      = <<-DESC
    Some description
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/‘
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :text => <<-LICENSE
    TEXT OF LICENSE
    LICENSE
                       }
  s.author           = { ‘Author’ => 'aa@bb.cc’ }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/..’, :tag => "v#{s.version}" }

  s.source_files     = '**/*.swift'
  s.frameworks       = 'Testable'

  s.platform         = :osx
  s.osx.deployment_target = '11.0'

end
```

### Steps

1. We connected Science Framework into App’s Workspace by:

```
 pod ’Science’, :git => ‘url to git repo’, :tag => ‘some tag’
```

2. We did `pod install` and it finished successfully
3. We run build Application 1 from Workspace(App)

### Expected

We expect that Application 1 is built successfully. So Testable dependency is correctly resolved for Science Pod and all the other targets in Workspace(App)

### Actual

Swift Compiler Error: No such module 'Testable' that is displayed for each `import Testable` inside Science Pod *.swift files

Comment: me too, have similar problem, someone please help!

Comment: In `.podspec` file [s.frameworks](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#frameworks) uses for system frameworks. Try use something like [s.weak_frameworks](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#weak_frameworks) or [s.dependency](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency).